# reghelper package: R graph_model error when model includes categorical covariates

Tags: r, plot, lme4, interaction-plot

I am using the *graph_model* function under "reghelper" package to plot interaction plot for my multilevel model.

My *y* and *x* are both continuous variables, I also have a moderator (*m*) and a covariate (*n*) which are categorical variables. Here's my code:

```
model <- lmer (y ~ x + m + x*m + n + (1|ID), data=data)
graph_model (model, y=y, x=x, lines=m)
```

However, I encountered the following error with the graph_model: "*Error in factor(grid[[term]], labels = c("-1 SD", "+1 SD")):invalid 'labels'; length 2 should be 1 or 0*".

I tried to

- delete the covariate variable *n*, or
- z-score *n* and *m* before entering them into the model

In both conditions, the error disappeared, and code ran successfully. But I wonder how I can get the code run by treating the categorical variables *n* and *m* still as factors, rather than z-scored?

Thank you!